# Limit cell contents using DevExpress SpreadsheetControl

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, spreadsheet

I am trying to truncate the cells in a column to a fixed number of characters using the DevExpress SpreadsheetControl.  I have it working by just iterating through each cell and manually truncating it using the code below:

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= rowCount; ++i)
 {
            worksheet.Columns[0][i].Value = worksheet.Columns[0][i].Value.ToString().Substring(0, 15);
 }
```

But this is extremely slow.  I was wondering if there is a way in the control to tell it to truncate the cells automatically?

**EDIT**

I found where I can export the sheet to a datatable and do the substring on it.  This is much faster:

```
        var dataTable = worksheet.CreateDataTable(worksheet.GetUsedRange(), true);
        var exporter = worksheet.CreateDataTableExporter(worksheet.GetUsedRange(), dataTable, true);
        exporter.Export();

        for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; ++i)
        {
            dataTable.Rows[i][0] = dataTable.Rows[i][0].ToString().Substring(0, 15);
        }

        worksheet.Import(dataTable, true, 0, 0);
```

I would still like to see if there is a better way built into the control or someplace else in the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is extremely slow because `SpreadsheetControl` is trying to update its content with any change in any cell. So, you just need to lock updates before running your code and unlock its after. For lock/unlock updates you can use [`SpreadsheetControl.BeginUpdate`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraSpreadsheetSpreadsheetControl_BeginUpdatetopic) and [`SpreadsheetControl.EndUpdate`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraSpreadsheetSpreadsheetControl_EndUpdatetopic) methods.
Here is example:

```
spreadsheetControl1.BeginUpdate();

var cells = spreadsheetControl1.ActiveWorksheet.GetUsedRange();

foreach (var cell in cells)
    cell.Value = cell.Value.ToString().Substring(0, 15);

spreadsheetControl1.EndUpdate();
```